# Setting format of Bookmark. VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

Just wondering if anyone has any insight to why this isn't setting my Bookmarks font size to 12. I've tried having it before and after I declare what the Bookmark text is. Also tried it with 12 and "12".

```
myWordDoc.Bookmarks("DefText").Range.Font.Size() = 12
    myWordDoc.Bookmarks("DefText").Range.Text = Final1
```

Any help wold be great.

Comment: Have you tried recording the macro in Word first to see how it handles the process?

Comment: Yes and I've tried using the method of selecting the bookmark and then using the selection function but no luck.

Comment: When I try making a selection and then changing the format that way, I get the error code "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

Comment: The macro that I created works fine doing what I described above but I still think/want a solution that can be included in my solution, rather a ms word macro. Would it have something to do with the fact that I'm using amicrosoft.office.interop.word over microsoft.office.tools.word?

Comment: Hmm! The approach I would have taken would be to create the macro in Word then copy the code out, obviously replacing the necessary object references in the .NET code. Either way (interop or office.tools) should have worked equally well, but they each have their little quirks.

Comment: Still couldn't get something like above to work but instead found out I can set the bookmark to specific Styles. See my solution below if you're interested. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a pretty straight forward solution to this after a little searching. Using MS-Word Styles.

```
myWordDoc.Bookmarks.Item("DefText").Range.Style = "Heading 3"
myWordDoc.Bookmarks.Item("DefText").Range.Style = "Defs"
myWordDoc.Bookmarks("DefText").Range.Text = Final1
```

The first Style "Heading 3" formats the text to Times NR and 12pt, then the second one "Defs" formats it to a numbered list. (For some sort of reason the "Defs" style only formats the numbering not the content)

The Final1 is a string of definitions built from a checkedboxlist. Here's an example:

```
For Each Def In CheckedListBox4.CheckedItems
If Def = "Other 1" Then Final1 = Final1 & TextBox2.Text & vbCrLf
If Def = "Other 2" Then Final1 = Final1 & TextBox41.Text & vbCrLf
If Def = "Other 3" Then Final1 = Final1 & TextBox42.Text & vbCrLf
If Def = "Other 4" Then Final1 = Final1 & TextBox43.Text & vbCrLf
If Def = "Other 5" Then Final1 = Final1 & TextBox44.Text & vbCrLf
Next
```

This was helpful with using styles:
http://www.docs.is.ed.ac.uk/skills/documents/3738/3738.pdf